# hasMany relationship - deselecting set value from view - does not update DB accordingly

Tags: grails

I have seen this behaviour on a few different locations lets say:

```
class fruits {
 static hasMany=[preapples:Apples, apples: Apples, postapples: Apples ]
}

static mapping = {
 preapples cascade: 'lock'
 apples cascade: 'lock'
 postapples cascade: 'lock'
}
static constraints = {
  preapples nullable:true
  apples nullable:true
  postapples nullable:true
}
```

When the views are generated if on fruits I select many apples apple1 apple2 etc

If I return now and change from apple1 + apple2 to just apple1 - everything is ok

If I deselect all as in if there was only 1 selected and I choose ctrl to unhighlight it - which clearly shows nothing has been selected - when I submit form the value is not actually removed.

Is this something to do with nullable ? or am I missing something obvious

I have added nullable true as suggested which has made no difference from selecting values then unselecting it.

I have also modified actual sql table structure (naming to apples and fruits but before making change / dropping table and after making change having it recreate table - there was no difference to nullable (already nullable)

```
mysql> describe fruits_apples;
+-----------------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                             | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| fruits_apples_id     | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| apples_id                  | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| fruits_postapples_id | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| fruits_preapples_id  | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
|


mysql> describe fruits_shell_scripts;
+-----------------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                             | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| fruits_apples_id     | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| apples_id                  | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| fruits_postapples_id | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| fruits_preapples_id  | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Regards

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Comment: I am sure I have seen this across 2.2.X 2.3.4 and currently it is on 2.3.7 doing this

Comment: If you make the relationship nullable: true does the same behavior exist?

Comment: no different - I will update question with more info